# 500 Internal Server Error after installing VS10sp1-KB983509

Tags: visual-studio-2010, servicepacks

When I tried to use an Ajax control toolkit, I get a grey out error and searching around they said installing VS10 Service pack could help to solve the problem. So I did install it and now I got a serious problem:

I can no longer load the website that I can load normally before, it shows this error:

```
Server Error. 500 - Internal server error.
```

I tried many ways and finally found this one looks quite close to what happened to me:

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842329
```

And I tried what it suggested:

```
go to C:\Windows\system32\mcfc42.dll-> properties\security\Edit\Add
```

Added:

```
Iwam_computername or computername\Iwam_computername
```

Also added:

```
Everyone
```

Allow Full control to all.
Restart server. But still the same problem. Please help me to fix this problem, unfortunately my server did not install backup option before I install VS SP1 so I could not recover to the previous point. Any solution ? If I cannot access it, no way I can code and test my website...

Comment: I don't know if I can uninstall VS service pack and will it helps to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this. At first, to narrow down the problem I load the website at server side (not at client side) then I see this error lines in my web.config file, I think when I click at property at project in VS and choose .net 4.0 then back to 3.5 it add some duplicate to my web.config file. I just add all the first lines related to .net 3.5 and keep the xml format correct then it works fine now! Many thanks !!